# Integration Testing requires consecutive builds?

Tags: automated-testing, continuous-integration, integration-testing, build-verification-test

If I have several code-level integration tests, and my integration strategy is to integrate the components in a bottom-up manner, should I perform a build for each integration level of the modules? Or should I just run all tests in a single build?

Answer (score 5):

What do you think?

Should you eat one meal at a time and 2 to 3 meals a day? 
Or 
should you eat sufficient meals for 30 days at once and enjoy the remaining 29 days?

Keep things as simple as possible! Combining everything and testing it all at once may make things too complicated to handle...

Comment: As simple as possible, but not any simpler.

Comment: Can please elaborate?

Comment: It was a joke, in the spirit of your answer. Commonly attributed to Einstein: http://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/05/13/einstein-simple/

Comment: Okay! Sorry I didn't get the joke... :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is valid only for the first integration, where you make the first build.
You should make a build every time you add something new...integrate and test as often as you can and you will get information.